# GTM Creating one instance and push data to dataLayer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-tag-manager

```
angular.module('project', [
  'ngRoute',
  'toastr', 
  'satellizer',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngStorage',
  'truncate',
])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$authProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider,  $authProvider) {
  'use strict';


  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(false);

  $routeProvider

    // Root URL.
    .when('/', {
      redirectTo: '/login',
      title: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/login', {

      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'login',
      title: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl : 'register.html',
      controller : 'register',
      title : 'Register'
    })
    .otherwise('/login');


}])
.run(['$window', '$localStorage', '$http', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$route', '$log', 'APP_VERSION',  '$templateCache', '$timeout', function ($window, $localStorage, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $route, $log, APP_VERSION, $templateCache, $timeout) {
  'use strict';
  $log.info('Project Version: ' + APP_VERSION);

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

})

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'myEvent',
    'myData': {
      'url': 'datalayer.com',
      'title': 'datalayer instance',
      'type': 'stories'
    },
    CartInfo: {
      'ecommerce': "ecommerce"
    }
  });

  });
}])
```

Creating always the times new instance for each page. how can I push data into dataLayer without creating the extra instance?

Please guide thanks a ton

Updated the code now take a look 
Please also assist what cause its creating new instance as well thank you once again

Comment: can you post your app code with defined route?

Comment: Updated the code Dipak

Comment: which angularjs version are you using